# No Sql in IOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, mongodb, nosql

The backend database of the IOS application is NOSQL / Mongo DB. We have to store the data offline when the user is not connected to the internet & and sync later when he is online.

i gone through the couchbase ios tutorial .

What is the best way to store data locally & sync with server later.

Kindly provide the architectural inputs for the above.

Comment: You need use Core Data. You will have do your Data Model according to the MongoDB data model and your web services (API).

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented with multiple ways of doing this and CoreData is really unbeatable. All the backend is done by Apple with none of the 'hard stuff' done by you. It's quite easy to implement an SQL database app using the SQLite C API, however, cloud synchronisation is another story altogether. Core Data can be used with iCloud which of course stores the data and syncs only when the device is connected to the internet.